# Implementing a Postek Printer on my .NET c# application

Tags: c#, .net, printing

So i created a .net c# application that does store article codification, and also bought a **Postek c168** barcode printer, and i want to create a section on my application that prints texts and images to the direct thermal labels with the printer, i also downloaded a dll file for developers on the official printer website, my question is on how to use the dll file or how to implement the printer on my application.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded SDK contains the manual for SDK functions "Postek API Manual_CDFPSK V3.01.pdf". I do not want to be sarcastic, but maybe you should start reading that document first.

My initial observation is that DLL contains some native functions that you can call over interop.

Comment: thanks for answering, i've read the document and understood some of the functions, my question was on how use that dll file at least an example to start with.